# Facebook Graph API Checking in to events

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I got an anroid app and im getting all the events from some pages. Any way i can have the user check in to the event?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible any more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-api-4-24:

> `/event` node — You can no longer perform `POST` operations on the `attending`, `maybe`, `interested`, and `declined` edges.